# Determine the value $(1^2 +3^2 + \ldots 99^2)-(2^2 + 4^2 +\ldots 100^2)+(4+8+\ldots200)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

I'm trying to find the value of the following:

$(1^2 +3^2 + 5^2 + \ldots + 99^2)-(2^2 + 4^2 + 6^2 + \ldots + 100^2)+(4+8+12 + \ldots +200)$

Got the last part of the question, but I'm stuck on the first two parts.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Should there be a square on the $100?$.  Do you know the formula for the sum of all the squares from $1^2$ to $n^2$?

Comment: @RossMillikan yes there should be one, sorry, I must have missed it. I don't know that formula. Our teacher just gave us this assignment without telling us anything, unfortunately.

Comment: It will be cubic in $n$.  Can you derive it?

Comment: Type `1^2+2^2+` into Google and you will get some suggestions.

Comment: @David Thank you so much! I think I got it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reorder the squares as $(1^2-2^2)+(3^2-4^2)+(5^2-6^2)+...(99^2-100^2)=-(3+7+11+...+199)$.  Then the required quantity will be $(4-3)+(8-7)+...+(200-199)=1+1+1+...+1$ and you are to count the number of $1$'s.